# Does "the military" refer to any military?

Tags: phrases, idioms, terminology, military

When someone uses the term "the military" is it implied they are talking about the military of the current country they are in, or any military? For example I sometimes see on application forms "Have you ever served in the military?" wouldn't it be more correct to have "Have you ever served in a military?" or "the US military"?

Is this an idiom in English that "the" refers to "any" in this context?

Another way to formulate this question: how would one phrase a question if they wanted to know if someone has actively been part of *any* military, regardless of which country they served for. For example if you were in the US and had a conversation with a man who appeared not to be from there (e.g. he spoke with a Russian accent) would it be more correct to ask "have you ever served in a military?" as it is probable that he hadn't served in the US one.

Comment: Unless you are a mercenary or in the extraordinarily special forces (mostly for ceremonious or security unit), I don't think there is any country which hires a non-national into their armed forces. In other words, each country has only one military and that's *the* military.

Comment: In general, the meaning is context-dependent.  On an application form it would be ambiguous, though (if I couldn't ask for clarification) I would take it to mean the US military, as US military service has some implications with regard to employment "preference", etc.

Comment: @Rathony yes but an emigrant could have served in his original countries military, therefore the answer to the question "has he served in the military" may be different than "any military".

Comment: @Celeritas Well, then it means "the military of a country where you resided before immigration". The answer would be "Yes, in (a country name)".

Comment: @Rathony my father, a Dutch citizen with permanent residency in the US, was subject to the draft during the Vietnam War.   American Samoa citizens are not US citizens, yet a high number serve in the US military.

Comment: @user662852  [The link](http://www.military.com/join-armed-forces/join-the-military-basic-eligibility.html) states "You must be a U.S. citizen or resident alien". I believe your father was a "resident alien". I think each country has different rules in terms of a resident alien.

Comment: @Celeritas /s/countries/country's

Comment: @rathony  I'm French I can serve in a lot of military forces in Europe as a foreigner. Also the Legion (the the Spanish one or French one) have accepted any nationalities for more than a hundred year.  I served in the Irish reserve and one of the question  was if I had served  in the military before. Though i don't remember the exact wording.  http://www.military.ie/reserve/faq/

Comment: @P.Obertelli Well, I think Europe is a different story and you have one single currency there. Can you join the U.K military? I doubt it.

Comment: @rathony  You can join the Irish reserve even as non European under some conditions, and you can join the Fench legion as a Zimbabwean . What you said is wrong, that's it. As for Uk "There are about 7000 Commonwealth citizens serving in the British Army from outside the UK." But i suppose Commonwealth is a different story, and the French legion is a different story and the Israeli force recruiting you as long as you've got a jew in your ancestor...see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_militaries_that_recruit_foreigners

Comment: @P.Obertelli I am sorry, but I don't understand what makes you think what I said is wrong. I know only Swiss nationals can join the Pontifical Swiss Guard and  they are mercenaries. I mentioned "unless you are a mercenary or in the extraordinarily special forces (mostly for ceremonious or security unit)", is it wrong? Those people who could join the Israeli military are mercenaries. I don't think Israel would accept a non-national if they have enough population for its military.

Comment: @Rathony you reminded me of an interesting argument I once heard. What's the difference between a soldier in a military and a mercenary? They both have the same job and they both get paid; a soldier does not necessarily agree with the cause he is fighting for and a mercenary may care about his. There is no difference between a soldier and a mercenary.

Answer (score 5):

Its not an idiom.  The "the" here is not synonymous with "any".  "The" is the [definite article](http://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm).  It refers to a specific military.  Which one in particular will have to be determined by context.  Generally it would be the military of the country you are *in*, but it may also be the military *of the country you are talking about*. For instance Americans in America are probably referring to the US Military, but Americans in, say, Thailand might be talking about the Thailand Military.

Comment: How could it be reworded to mean any military, for example is it good English to say "served in any military"? I guess so but it sounds strange to me.

Comment: Actually "served in any military" is perfectly fine.  That makes it clear that you don't care which military, as long as it was some branch of some country's armed forces.  Doesn't sound strange to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption would be, when seeing this in a United States setting, that most people in the USA do not venture outside of America (aside from vacations and assignments). So by saying "the military", it is referring the United States military and has very high inclusion rate while using as little space as possible.

It's kind of like address information where they ask you street and state, but do not ask country because it's assumed if you are putting state then you are in America.

Real life does not operate with 100% inclusion.

If you were in the Khmer Rouge, I would just leave it at circling Y and not going any further into detail.

Answer (score -1):

"The military" is synonymous with "any military", or "the armed forces", which when viewed this way, would include all of the world's different armed forces.

"Military" can be a plural noun, meaning "all the militaries" ("all the armed forces"), or an adjective, meaning "belonging or relating to an armed force".

This isn't an idiom.

You would say "Have you ever served in the military?" or "Have you ever served in the armed forces?"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military